# Is there a software that allows RS232 sniffing and TCP/UDP listening

Tags: software-rec, logging, tcp, sniffing, rs232

I am looking for a software that would fulfill the following requirements:

- Able to "sniff" communication over RS232 (like [PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) and [Advanced Serial Data Logger](http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-data-logger.htm))
- Able to listen to a given address/port for TCP/UDP broadcasts (like [Hercules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html))
- Optionally could "sniff" IEEE488 communication
- Optimally would be free

Is there such a magical tool?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what OS you're using.

For Linux, try socat or graag's SockSniffer on the `/dev/ttySx` device which represents the serial port:

- [Can I monitor a local unix domain socket like tcpdump?](https://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump)
- http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/
- http://graag.blogspot.com/2007/10/unix-socket-sniffer.html

For Windows, there are many solutions available with a basic Google search.